# Идентификация пользователя, открывшего Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Есть Google Form, вопросы в которой формируются динамически. Для каждого пользователя в определённый момент времени блок вопросов должен быть свой. Как идентифицировать пользователя, открывающего форму?
У пользователя есть GoogleID.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение вопроса. Оно, как всегда, лежало на поверхности.

```
var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
```